# что я делаю не так

Tags: jquery, attr

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="#fixed-a-1" href="4to9delayunetak.com">text</a>
<a id="#fixed-a-2">text</a>
<script>
  user_url = $('#fixed-a-1').attr('href');
  $("#fixed-a-2").attr("href", "'+user_url+'");
</script>
```

Comment: Для начала, вы задаете вопрос, где приходится самому догадываться, что именно вы хотите получить на выходе своего кода.

Comment: Вы не поверите, не получилось))

Comment: id конечно я без # написал, прост тут я нечаянно. Код который я написал вставляет <a id="#fixed-a-2" href="+user_url+">text</a> . А твой ничего не делает, хотя я думал что так правильнее будет. jquer js я почти ничего не смыслю. Помоги пожалуйста

Comment: Спасибо Станислав. Все заработало)) Прости)))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Неверный `id` в разметке. Чтобы jQuery нашел *#fixed-a-2* id у элемента должно быть **без** `#`: `<a id="fixed-a-1"`
2. Лишние кавычки в строке `, "'+user_url+'");`. Они тут вообще не нужны.

В итоге может получится так:

```js
var user_url = $('#fixed-a-1').attr('href');
$("#fixed-a-2").attr("href", user_url);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="fixed-a-1" href="4to9delayunetak.com">text</a>
<a id="fixed-a-2">text</a>
```

Comment: Вопрос 2. var user_url = $('#fixed-a-1').attr('href');
$("#fixed-a-2").attr("href", user_url);
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="fixed-a-1" href="4to9delayunetak.com">text</a>
<a id="fixed-a-2">text</a>

Comment: @АсланАйдынгалиулы, если у тебя появился _новый_ вопрос, задай его отдельно